Assign JSON file value to a variable in Jenkinsfile with jq
I have a JSON file which has the following structure:
{
"name":"John",
"address": "24th Avenue"
}

I am trying to extract address information from this JSON file in one Jenkinsfile stage and assign it to a variable and use this variable in the following steps, my code is as such:
parameters {

        string(
          name: 'json_file_location',defaultValue:"config.json")
}

stages {
    stage("read json file"){
            steps {
                sh """
                    address=jq -r '.address' ${params.json_file_location}
                """
        }
    }

    stage("print"){
            steps {
                sh """
                    echo "$address"
                """
        }
    }
}

But above code is not able to assign jq result correctly to address variable, I have also tried method described here. But still not working.
What is the correct way to assign jq result to a variable so that I can reuse it in a different stage?

If you want to create a Groovy variable from a JSON file, you don't have to use the sh step and jq - Jenkins has the built-in readJson step. This should be wrapped in a script block for a declarative pipeline (which yours is):
steps {
  script {
    def address = readJson(file: params.json_file_location).address
  }
}

Further, if you want to share that variable between the stages, you should either use an environment variable, or define a global variable outside of pipeline block - because the stages are executed independently (possibly even on different agents):
def address // not needed if you use the environment variables 

pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    string(
      name: 'json_file_location',
      defaultValue: 'config.json'
    )
  }
  stages {
    stage("read json file") {
      steps {
        script {
          address = readJson(file: params.json_file_location).address
          // or env.ADDRESS = readJson(file: params.json_file_location).address
        } 
      }
    }
    stage("print") {
      steps {
        println address
        // or println env.ADDRESS
      }
    }
  }
}


As mentioned in the comments by @Benjamin W, the problem here is that you are currently setting a bash shell variable address but that is only in scope for that one step, what you are looking for is to set a groovy method to the stdOut of the shell step.
So doing say:
address = sh (
  returnStdout: true,
  script: "jq -r '.address' ${params.json_file_location}"
).trim()

Should make a groovy variable for you that you are able to use later in your Jenkinsfile.
